# Android,Retrofit how to use @Headers?

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

Currently, I am using Retrofit in Android.

Every REST call have different headers. I find there is key word @Header in retrofit in Retrofit, the example is as follows:

```
 @GET("/tasks")
    Call<List<Task>> getTasks(@Header("Content-Range") String contentRange);
```

But I also find another key words @Headers, How can I use Headers in Retrofit, because I have many headers, so I think @Headers maybe better.

Don't post okHttpClient method, I have already known how to use that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`@Headers` is for static headers, arguments cannot go there.

```
@Headers({
    "X-Something: Foo",
    "X-Else: Bar",
    "Cache-Control: max-age=300000"
})
@GET("/getStuff") <Task> getStuff();
```

if you got many **different** headers per call then you need to use `@Header` or rethink your API on a backend. Alternatively you may add headers using Interceptor but I do not think this is the way to go.

Comment: @Headers({
    "X-Something: Foo",
    "X-Else: Bar",
    "Cache-Control: max-age=300000"
}) is a static way, Is there a dynamic way ? Just like the code I post, but with headers?